# Matlab function handles and C++ function pointers

Tags: c++, matlab

Is it possible to make a Matlab function handle compatible with a C++ function pointer? I am trying to call a C++ function from Matlab that takes in a C++ function pointer. For example:

> C++:

```
void Cfunction( C++functionPointer);
```

> Matlab:

```
function out Mfunction(functionHandle)
     out= Cfunction(functionHandle)
```

Unfortunately I can not post the code because it is confidential. So I want my Matlab program to call a C++ function using calllib(). One of the parameters for the C++ function is a function pointer. In Matlab, I tried using a Matlab function handle as the parameter in callib but this did not work. Therefore, I am having difficulty calling the C++ function from Matlab.

**Matlab is saying that the C++ compiler will not accept the Matlab function handle type for its pointer argument.**

Thanks

Comment: Read about the MEX API.

Comment: What is `funcionHandle`? Do you want your C++ program to call a Matlab function? It would be more helpful if you provided a complete example, including the steps you took to compile the C++ code and how you called `Mfunction` from the Matlab shell.

Comment: Just edited question, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so, from what I understand, you have a library written in C++ with a function (let me call it `functionFromMyCppLibrary`) that you nee to run. One of the arguments this function requires is a function pointer.

I'm assuming this function pointer must be a C++ function. If `functionFromMyCppLibrary` needs to call an arbitrary Matlab function, then my answer does not apply. However there's a Q&A in the Mathworks exchange that you might find helpful: [How do I pass function handles to C++ mex function in MATLAB 7.8 (R2009a)?](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/96775-how-do-i-pass-function-handles-to-c-mex-function-in-matlab-7-8-r2009a). You will probably need to modify `CppFunction` below so that it makes Matlab call `feval`. It gets actually easier if you can hardcode a Matlab function name in `CppFunction()`.

`callTheCppThing.cpp`:

```
#include "mex.h"
#include "myCppLibrary.h"

void CppFunction()
{
    // The function your C++ library requires as a function pointer
    // You could use mexCallMATLAB here to call a Matlab function,
    // but it will get trickier if you can't hard-code the name of
    // the Matlab function here
}

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, mxArray *prhs[])
{
    // Process however you need the arguments
    functionFromMyCppLibrary(CppFunction);

    // Create the output variables and return whatever Matlab needs
}
```

You can compile with

```
mex callTheCppThing.cpp
```

(Add to this command line anything that is required to link this C++ with your library.)

And you call from Matlab with

```
callTheCppThing
```

This removes the need of Matlab passing any kind of handle to your C++ library. (If you have no possibility of writing different wrappers in C++, then check the linked Q&A from Mathworks. It's tricky, but possible.)

Comment: I appreciate your response. Thank you! However, in reference to the example you gave, CppFunction is a Matlab function. Therefore, my 'mexFunction' from the C++ library needs to be able to reference the Matlab 'CppFunction', hence the Matlab function handle. Hope this makes sense, and thanks again.

Comment: I was thinking of maybe making a libpointer set to the function handle but that's not working

Comment: One possibility is to make it so that `CppFunction()` calls the Matlab function using `mexCallMATLAB`. However there are several limitations. For instance, the Matlab function is specified by name. Also passing arguments to the function is hell. I'll give you the most basic example only.

Comment: Actually, I think this will help you better: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/96775-how-do-i-pass-function-handles-to-c-mex-function-in-matlab-7-8-r2009a